# Sorting problem regarding Last Modified Date in Splunk query

Tags: splunk

I have a problem regarding sorting in SPLUNK.

I want to make automated reports and I want to sort in a calendar the amount of tickets one day.

A ticket has these time stamps:

```
ACTUAL_END_DATE="2018-10-29 01:00:00.0", 
ACTUAL_START_DATE="2018-10-29 00:00:00.0", 
CLOSED_DATE="2019-06-16 12:56:00.0",  
COMPLETED_DATE="2019-06-06 10:47:46.0",  
EARLIEST_START_DATE="2018-10-23 11:20:42.0",  
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE="2019-06-16 12:56:07.0",  
RFA_DATE="2018-10-23 11:20:42.0", 
RFC_DATE="2018-10-22 15:19:00.0",  
SFA_DATE="2019-06-06 10:47:02.0", 
SFR_DATE="2019-06-06 10:46:52.0",  
SCHEDULED_DATE="2019-06-06 10:47:06.0", 
SCHEDULED_END_DATE="2018-10-29 01:00:00.0", 
SCHEDULED_START_DATE="2018-10-29 00:00:00.0",  
SUBMIT_DATE="2018-10-22 15:18:53.0",
```

I sort by two tokens, the earliest is "@mon" and the latest is "now".

Unfortunately, it sorts by LAST_MODIFIED_DATE and I have 62 tickets in one day. All that have ACTUAL_START_DATE in different months, as you can change a ticket after it closed to add details.

This is my query:

```
 stats latest(STATUS_REASON) as STATUS_REASON latest(CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS) as CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS latest(_time) as _time latest(CHANGE_TIMING) as CHANGE_TIMING by INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE_ID 
| where CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS !="Cancelled" 
| timechart count span=1D
```

How can I sort them and get rid of the count from LAST_MODIFIED_DATE and have them shown by ACTUAL_START_DATE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timechart` command is ordering by _time, not by LAST_MODIFIED_DATE (although the two fields may have the same values).  To use a different field, assign that field's value to _time.

```
stats latest(STATUS_REASON) as STATUS_REASON latest(CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS) as CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS latest(_time) as _time latest(CHANGE_TIMING) as CHANGE_TIMING by INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE_ID 
| where CHANGE_REQUEST_STATUS !="Cancelled" 
| eval _time = strptime(ACTUAL_START_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N")
| timechart count span=1D
```

Comment: I tried assigning different fields to _time and I always get "No results found."

Comment: I forgot to add latest(ACTUAL_START_DATE) as ACTUAL_START_DATE!

It works like a charm! Thank you!